# htaccess redirect but exclude images

Tags: image, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to use htaccess redirect to a file, but can't get the image to display.

I want to redirect ANY request to mydomain.com or www.mydomain.com to www.mydomain.com/test.html

This is the content of my htaccess file:

```
# Turn rewriting on
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/test.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=*\.png$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* /test.html
```

I have this line of code in my test.html file:

```
<img src="image.png" alt="My Image">
```

But the image doesn't display at all, I just get a broken image. I also tried using absolute path for image, same thing.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try replacing your .htaccess file with the following

```
# Turn rewriting on
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#if the request does not end with test.html or is not a .png
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(test\.html|\.png)$ [NC]
# Rewrite it to test.html
RewriteRule .* /test.html  [L]
```

Answer (score 6):

This will exclude various types of images

```
#if the request does not end with .gif,.png or jpg 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.gif|\.jpg|\.png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index.html$ index.php [NC]
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.png$ [NC]
```

Not familiar with `!.` prefix. Check the [`RewriteCond` Docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)

Comment: yeah, sorry, I have no idea how that typo got there. But the code in my htaccess file was correct and I just edited my first post.

Comment: From the RewriteCond docs, when `=` is used the pattern is treated as plain text, so this may not work

Answer (score 0):

Try -

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(ico|gif|jp?g|png|swf|rm|mov|mp?g)$ [NC]
```