# Exclude all images from mod_rewrite rule

Tags: image, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rule

I am a htaccess novice, constantly learning, and would really appreciate any help with what I would think to be a quick & easy problem for any experienced htaccess person to solve.

**Backgroud:**

I have a Wordpress site with the same category slug and category names as some of the directories and subdirectories in which I have images in the sites root directory. If a directory path matches category slug and category name Wordpress will by default return a 403 when trying to view the category slug and category name. I managed to solve that problem with this excellent guide:
http://www.narga.net/how-to-solve-403-forbidden-wordpress-permalink-clash-folder-name/

And implementet this code in my htaccess:

```
# Fix 403 errors on existing directories; WordPress overrides.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(example)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

That problem solved.

**The problem:**

This has however caused a another problem. Off and on I use Redirects for Wordpress categories and then images that have matching directories with category slug and category names are also redirected resulting in a broken image link. From what I have been able to understand I need to exclude any request ending in a image format .gif .jpg .png from the rewrite above and pictures should show?

From what I manged to understand I should add something like this (see the last post on link) somewhere to the code above:
[htaccess redirect but exclude images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8649456/htaccess-redirect-but-exclude-images)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.gif|\.jpg|\.png)$ [NC]
```

Being a novice I don't really know how to change/add this to the code above for it to be properly implemented. So if someone could be so kind to show me, it would really be kind.

**My complete htaccess file:**

```
<files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>

<files wp-config.php>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>

Options All -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# Fix 403 errors on existing directories; WordPress overrides.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(example)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

<Files 403.shtml>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>

Redirect 302 /example/specimen/ /
```