# Unable to access image in sub folder in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

Hi I install custom PHP backend in WordPress sub directory and make some image uploader and upload image in sub sub folder now am not able to access or display image from that folder due to WordPress .htaccess any one short out my problem

my WordPress path is

www.mywordpress.com

and sub folder path is

www.mywordpress.com/mem/web/user/abc.jpg

not able to open image nor any dir after mem folder.

.htacess code:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: you can add an ignore rule for image request which will  bypass this restriction. you can refer this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8649456/htaccess-redirect-but-exclude-images

Comment: @Sam i try some rules but none of the work so ask here !

Comment: Is there any error showing while accessing the image folders? Also have you checked the permissions?

Comment: @ShahrozeNawaz yes its show 403 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory or you do not have enough permissions to access the resource

Comment: So i think you have 644 permission set on the image folder. change the permission to 775. use command `chmod -R 775 image folder name`. check if it works

Comment: nope problem solved adding this Options +Indexes